# XHR request to RESTlet fails, typing it in works

Tags: rest, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I am having a challenge with RESTlet where I can access the URL to my RESTful application at http://localhost:8080/asWeb/r/WebVersion and retrieve JSON formatted text, and I see the Dojo XHR working from my mobile phone when SSH port forwarded into my box. The problem is whenever I run from local host I get the error:

STATUS: 0 (RequestError: Unable to load http://localhost:8080/asWeb/r/WebVersion status: 0)

{…}message: "Unable to load /asWeb/r/Login status: 0"response: {…}getHeader: function _420()options: {…}data: ""handleAs: "text"ioArgs: {…}args: Object { url: "/asWeb/r/Login", handleAs: "application/json", load: load(), … }error: Object { message: "Unable to load /asWeb/r/Login status: 0", stack: "_31e@http://localhost:8080/asWeb/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js:8:71685\n_418@http://localhost:8080/asWeb/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js:8:92086\n", status: 0, … }handleAs: "application/json"query: ""url: "/asWeb/r/Login"xhr: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }**proto**: Object { … }**proto**: Object { data: null, sync: false, method: "GET", … }status: 0text: ""url: "/asWeb/r/Login"xhr: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }**proto**: {…}**defineGetter**: function **defineGetter**()**defineSetter**: function **defineSetter**()**lookupGetter**: function **lookupGetter**()**lookupSetter**: function **lookupSetter**()constructor: function Object()hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()toSource: function toSource()toString: function toString()valueOf: function valueOf()responseText: ""stack: "_31e@http://localhost:8080/asWeb/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js:8:71685\n_418@http://localhost:8080/asWeb/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js:8:92086\n"status: 0xhr: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }**proto**: Object { name: "RequestError", constructor: _31e(), stack: "" } dojo.js:8:56587

Again, this is what it should return when pasting it in address bar:

```
[{"Changes":"More backend work on Javacode.","Version":"14.19","Date":"2018-02-16"},{"Changes":"More work on Dojo/Java development","Version":"14.18","Date":"2018-02-15"},{"Changes":"More work on Dojo/Java deployment","Version":"14.17","Date":"2018-02-14"},{"Changes":"More work on Dojo/Java deployment","Version":"14.16","Date":"2018-02-13"},{"Changes":"Work on Dojo, work on Java version","Version":"14.15","Date":"2018-02-11"}]
```

I followed numerous tutorials online to integrate CORS into RESTlet, verify I'm preventing default on my AJAX/XHR request, and have valid data since I can access the URL if I copy and paste it from the Firefox inspector panel.

https://github.com/f00dl3/asWeb

I posted most of the code here. I also included a "vanillaXhr.js" file which experiences the same issue using the "vanilla" way - so it's not Dojo's fault.

For what it's worth, here's jQuery that fails at this too:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseForRestlet+"/Login",
        dataType: 'json',
        type : 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            window.alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ajaxOptions, errorThrown, result) { 
            window.alert(" jqXHR: "+jqXHR+"\n textStatus: "+textStatus+"\n    errorThrown: "+errorThrown+"\n ajaxOptions: "+ajaxOptions+"\n result: "+result);
            console.log(jqXHR.status);
        }
    }); 

});
```

I added CORS to my web.inf in Netbeans:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost, https://localhost, http://127.0.0.1, https://127.0.0.1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And in my RESTlet I have the following on my Application JAVA file:

```
public AnthonyRestlet() {

    CorsService corsService = new CorsService();
    corsService.setAllowingAllRequestedHeaders(true);
    corsService.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Arrays.asList(
            "http://localhost",
            "https://localhost",
            "http://127.0.0.1",
            "https://127.0.0.1"
    )));
    corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);
    corsService.setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions(true);
    getServices().add(corsService);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and it was really stupid simple.

All I had to do was in each Resource Java file change the @Get to @Get @Options

```
  @Get @Options
  public String represent() {

        GetWebAccessLogAction getWebAccessLogAction = new GetWebAccessLogAction(new WebAccessLogDAO());
        JSONArray webAccessLogs = getWebAccessLogAction.getWebAccessLogs();  
        return webAccessLogs.toString();

  }
```